# Updating nvarchar field to a non-english text

Tags: sql, encoding, character-encoding, sql-update

Say I have a table with 2 fields

```
Id   : int
Text : nvarchar(50)
```

now I want to set the text of items with ID higher than 50 to be some text **but not in english**

after the update query my table looks like this

```
Id      Text
...     ...
51      ????
52      ????
...     ...
```

edit:
my query

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Text = 'אבגד'
where Id > 50
```

Comment: Could you post your update query maybe?

Comment: @Stivan I edited and added the query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

put N before text like this

```
     set Text=N'אבגד'
```

Comment: Thanks! thats solved the problem. can you please explain to me what is this N? and also if I use C# or JAVA so get the results will I have to type this N as well?

Comment: It ensures the characters are converted into unicode see: http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/155859/why-do-we-need-to-put-n-before-strings-in-microsoft-sql-server

Comment: @Chris: not *converted* to Unicode - but **interpreted** as Unicode (to be totally nitpicky precise)

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE MyTable
SET Text = N'אבגד'
where Id > 50
```

If the above code does not work then you need to check the globalisation settings of all the code that deals with this data, from your database, data access and presentation layers. This includes SSMS.